# bpy.ops.fluid.bake_all() always overwrites

Tags: python, baking

I am running this command when I have already baked previously and I see that it still bakes overwriting the previous baking. I thought that baking was skipped when the cache_fluid folder was created.

I thought this command would work only if there was no other cache folder with that name, and, in case there was other folder, it would just stop, but in my case is overwriting the previous folder.

Is there a way of preventing this? Thanks!

Comment: That's intended and makes sense because you do not want to have redundant gigs of cache files you'll never use. I'd suggest up the cache version by changing your file name to something like `foo_v02`. In general I would recommend always manually figure out how it works using the UI in the first place, then try to implement it using python and please add the current state of your code if the question is about `bpy`, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't add my code because I am just trying the command, so there is no code basically. Just a one liner to see how this works. I mean I thought it skipped baking, not that it creates one new folder every time I press the button. And I also thought in order to bake again, deleting/cancelling the previous bake was needed. That's in fact what the UI shows you so I thought the command would work the same way. But in my case at least, the command is overwriting the folder previously created.

Comment: If there is still some errors in the question, I'll change it! I usually post code examples but being the case that I was only testing the command I thought it wasn't necessary!